# How to return a specific value when using entity_load?

Tags: entities

I want to loop through Paragraph bundles and return a string (image path `uri` string).

I can view the Paragraph arrays as such:

```
foreach ($variables['field_paragraphs'] as $i) {
  $entity = entity_load('paragraphs_item', array($i['value']));
  dpm($entity);
}
```

This returns each Paragraph bundle as an multidimensional array. I want to take the value of each `uri` key and place them in their own array.

To that effect I have tried `$image_path = $entity['ParagraphsItemEntity']['field_image']['und']['0']['uri'];`, but it returns nothing.

I've also tried making a function.

```
  function array_column_recursive(array $haystack, $needle)
    {
        $found = [];
        array_walk_recursive($haystack, function ($value, $key) use (&$found, $needle) {
            if ($key == $needle) {
                $found[] = $value;
            }
        });
        return $found;
    }
    print(array_column_recursive($entity, 'uri')[0]);
```

This gives me an error message.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare array_column_recursive();

(It doesn't seem to matter what the function is named; it will always have this error.)

Would anyone know how to simply get a value from a multidimensional array in Drupal?

Comment: Did you try entity metadata wrappers?

Comment: @Kevin, nope, didn't even know they existed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's what I did, after discovering Entity Metadata Wrappers:

```
//FORMATS ARRAY TO SOMETHING EASIER TO HANDLE
$entity_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('paragraphs_item', reset($entity));
//RETURN THE VALUE OF THE IMAGE ARRAY
$image = $entity_wrapper->field_image->value();
//RETURN THE (FULL) URL OF THE IMAGE
$file_url = file_create_url($image['uri']);
```